# Why is it that my $_SESSION or my 'if' statement won't trigger when split over two pages?

Tags: php

I am trying to make an email form that when an error occurs it displays a flash error message. I have the process split over two pages, the first is the contact.php page where the form is and the other is the validation.php page where the validation and email 'mail()' function is. I link the pages via a 'require_once("validation.php");' at the top of the contact.php page.

When I have them split over these two pages the flash message won't appear but when I have all of the code on one page only, the contact.php page, it does work. However, even though this problem is happening the email does send when the form is filled in, so I know the linking of the pages is working and some of the code is executing.

Any idea why this is occurring?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

contact.php:

```
<?php 
require_once("validation.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
   <main class="container">
            <div class="form-container">
            <?php

                echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST).'</pre>';
                echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['error']).'</pre>';
                if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
                    echo('<p style="color: red;">'.$_SESSION['error']." 
                    </p>\n");
                    unset($_SESSION['error']);
                }

             ?>

            <form action="contact.php" method="POST">
                <label for="name">Enter your name: </label><br>
                <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                <label for="email">Enter your email: </label><br>
                <input type="email" name="email"><br>
                <label for="subject">Subject line: </label><br>
                <input type="text" name="subject"> 
                <br>
                <label for="message">Message: </label><br>                                      
                <textarea name="message" cols="75" rows="10"> 
                </textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">

            </form>
             </div><!-- .form-container -->
        </main>
       </body>
      </html>
```

validation.php:

```
<?php 
 session_start();


 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);


    if ( strlen($name) < 1 || strlen($email) < 1 || strlen($subject) < 1 || 
strlen($message) < 1) {

        $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";
        header("Location: contact.php");
        return;

    } else {

        $to = "example@example.com";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

     }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Start the session using `session_start()` on every page in your app. Right at the top of every page

Comment: I tried adding session_start() to the contact page above the require_once() but I get an error saying "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the `session_start()` is in the `include` file on `contact.php` that also checks the `POST` from the form, which uses a redirect back to `contact.php`  that checks the `$_SESSION['error']`.

Comment: Show your separated page version.

Comment: @fyrye this is the separated version. Above I have the code for both the contact.php page and then the validation.php page. Did you mean the version where it's all in one single page?

Comment: @NiallTuohy You can't get post value after header location

Comment: Remove the `header("Location: contact.php");return;` You are already in `contact.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly that worked to display the message but now if I click page refresh it displays that pop up about resubmitting the form. The purpose of the `header("Location: contact.php");return;` was to make it so that if someone refreshes the page it will not display that. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the use of `return;` as opposed to `exit;`;
Since the include file is not terminated, the rest of the script is processed.

Your code should be edited as such:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);

    if (strlen($name) < 1 || strlen($email) < 1 || strlen($subject) < 1 ||
        strlen($message) < 1) {

        $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";
        header("Location: contact.php");
        exit;
    }
    //no need for else since when the if condition is true, it is terminated
    $to = "example@example.com";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

//...
```

---

*Edited to answer comment question:*

Include files are allowed to return a value such as an array just like a function. So when you used `return` it did not stop the rest of the script from executing at that point. It did however "leave" the include file. 
So your script added the `header` and then `returned void`, then continued to display the HTML content after the include.

For example:

```
<?php
//index.php
$value = include 'my_file.php'; 
var_dump($value);
```

```
<?php
//my_file.php
return ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

Since there was textual content after the `header`, the redirect was also not honored.

Comment: As this is code that is `required` that will kill the whole page script

Comment: @RiggsFolly included the entire script as opposed to just the edited portion. The `exit` is expected to kill the entire page in order for the redirect to execute.

Comment: hum, you are so fast for me :P

Comment: This works! Could you explain to me a little more the difference between `return`and `exit` and why this worked?

Comment: Since you are using exit and return within the global scope (not inside a function), then the behavior is almost the same.

Comment: I'm just surprised that doing `return` outside of a function context is not a syntax error.

Comment: @Mike see edited answer for an example of how it can be used.

Comment: @fyrye Yeah, I just checked out the docs. I've just never seen return used in anything but a function, so I didn't know it was even possible to use elsewhere. Returning a value from an include and setting a variable with the value returned just seems wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help!